# Does it make sense to use Angular and NestJS in a monorepo?

Tags: angular, architecture, nestjs, monorepo

Does it make sense to use Angular (Frontend) and NestJS (Backend) in a monorepo (e.g. Nx or Lerna)?

What kind of code could you share? I only can think of Models (e.g. User-Class). However, NestJS uses TypeORM, which "pollutes" the Model with additional decorates (`@Entity`, `@Column`, ...). These decorators are fine in a NestJS context, but you don't want these decorators in a Angular context.

Why does this still make sense? What are the advantages of it? What are your thoughts?

Comment: NestJS does not use TypeORM, it allows you to use it: you might choose another ORM solution. Besides that: an Entity is about your database model, what you will consume on frontend side are Data Model Object (DTO), not Entities.